# Why sharedPreferences doesn't work in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I used an edittext in the xml file and I want to save the text in the edittext when the user writes a text and onResume or onDestroy the program or closes the same program using the shared preference feature, but unfortunately the program crashes and closes

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var editText: EditText
    private val name = "MY_TEXT"
    private val key = "myStoreData"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext)
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE)
        val myValue = sharedPreferences.getString(key,"")
        editText.setText(myValue)
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE)
        var edit = sharedPreferences.edit()
        edit.putString("my Store Data",editText.text.toString())
        edit.apply()
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="Autofill,HardcodedText,LabelFor" />
```

I wanted the program to save the text but the program crashes

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided code and XML layout, I can see a couple of issues that might be causing the crash:

**1. XML Layout Issue:**
In your XML layout, the ID of the EditText is set to `editTextText`, but in your `MainActivity.kt` file, you are trying to find the EditText using the ID `edittext`. You need to use the same ID that you used in your XML layout to find EditText. Update your onCreate method as follows:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextText) // Use the correct ID here
}
```

**2. Incorrect Key for SharedPreferences:**
In the `onDestroy` method, you are using a different key when saving the text to SharedPreferences compared to what you use when retrieving the data in the `onResume` method. Update the key in the `onDestroy` method to match the one used in `onResume`:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE)
    var edit = sharedPreferences.edit()
    edit.putString(key, editText.text.toString()) // Use the same key here
    edit.apply()
}
```

After making these changes, your code should work as expected and save the text entered in the EditText.

Comment: This is not a problem solver because no text is saved when closing and reopening the app

Answer (score 0):

The crash is appearing because the id of the editText which is defined in your XML is different than what you are using in your Activity.

Instead of doing this:

```
editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext)
```

Do this:

```
editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextText)
```

and replace:

```
edit.putString("my Store Data",editText.text.toString())
```

with

```
edit.putString(key or "myStoreData",editText.text.toString())
```

I hope this helps.